# What is vritti in buddhism?

Tags: lay-buddhism

Those [yoga sutras of Patanjali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Sutras_of_Patanjali) and have come across called [vritti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vritti).  It's like a whirlpool in the mind not ocean. But what is the equivalent of *vritti* in Buddhism?

Comment: Wikipedia lists those suttas as "Part of a series on Hindu philosophy". Is this question on-topic on this site, or should it be on [Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @ChrisW what is vritti equivalent in buddhism? I think it's a fair inquiry

Comment: Perhaps it's called e.g. [discursive thinking](https://www.lionsroar.com/the-practice-of-not-thinking/) colloquially in English. Are you looking for an English word, or maybe Pali?

Comment: @ChrisW sir, i am looking for a pali/english description aka a concept